# Program Loops Very Quickly and Indefinitely? Can't Figure Out Why

Tags: python, class, loops, debugging, twitter

I'm working on a Tweet Manager program in python for my programming class. For the assignment, I'm supposed to create a Tweet class that stores the author of a tweet, the tweet itself, and the time the tweet was created. Then, I'm supposed to create a Twitter program that gives users a menu of options to choose from.

When I try to run my Twitter program, it opens without syntax errors, but prints the Menu over and over and over again really rapidly without stopping. I can't figure out what in my code is causing this problem.

Here is my Twitter code:

```
    import Tweet
    import pickle
    def main():
        try:
            load_file = open('tweets.dat', 'rb')
            tweets = pickle.load('tweets.dat')
            load_file.close()
        except:
            tweet_list = []
        while (True):
            choice = display_menu()

            #Make a Tweet
            if (choice == 1):
                tweet_author = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
                tweet_text = input("What would you like to tweet? ")
                print()
            if len(tweet_text) > 140:
                print("Tweets can only be 140 characters!\n")
            else:
                print(tweet_author, ", your Tweet has been saved.")

            age = 0
            tweets = tweet.Tweet(tweet_author, tweet_text)

            tweet_list.append(tweets)

            try:
                output_file = open('tweets.dat', 'wb')
                pickle.dump(tweets, output_file)
                output_file.close()
            except:
                print("Your tweets could not be saved!")

            #View Recent Tweets
            elif (choice == 2):
                print("Recent Tweets")
                print("--------------")
                if len(tweet_list) == 0:
                    print("There are no recent tweets. \n")
                for tweets in tweet_list[-5]:
                    print(tweets.get_author(), "-", tweets.get_age())
                    print(tweets.get_text(), "\n")

            #Search Tweets
            elif (choice == 3):
                match = 0
                tweet_list.reverse()

                if tweet_list == []:
                    print("There are no tweets to search. \n")

                search = input("What would you like to search for? ")
                for tweets in tweet_list:
                    if (search in tweets.get_text()):
                        match = 1
                    if match = 1:
                        print("Search Results")
                        print("--------------")
                        print(tweets.get_author(), "-", tweets.get_age())
                        print(tweets.get_text(), "\n")
                    elif match == 0:
                        print("No tweets contained", search, "\n")

            #Quit
            elif (choice == 4):
                print("Thank you for using the Tweet Manager!")
                exit()

    def display_menu():
        print("Tweet Menu")
        print("------------")
        print()
        print("1. Make a Tweet")
        print("2. View Recent Tweets")
        print("3. Search Tweets")
        print("4. Quit")
        print()

    main()
```

Comment: `choice = display_menu` should be `choice = display_menu()`

Comment: minimal example? e.g: 3 lines of code?

Comment: it's written that way in the actual code, must have mistyped here. thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem, the code is doing precisely what you told it to.

`display_menu` does exactly what the name implies: displays the menu. The `main` function calls that function inside a loop.

At no point do you actually ask for any input corresponding to the menu options.

Answer (score 0):

`display_menu` always returns `None` - that's the default if you don't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your `display_menu` function doesn't actually give a value.

Change the last line of that function (`print()`) to

```
return input()
```

or if you are using python 2.x

```
return raw_input()
```

Comment: that would return a string.

Comment: It will in python 3 which I assumed he was using due to the `()` in print. Editted for python 2 as well

Answer (score 0):

Display menu does not retrieve any input into choice... Just displays the menu.
Thus, no if is matched and you loop indefinitely.